# Como validar CEP com AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma aplicação onde uso CEP para fazer parte do cadastro.
Só o CEP já basta e precisaria que fosse validado o CEP e no final da validação dispare uma função.
Como posso fazer isso?

html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cep" ng-keyup="pegaCep()" placeholder="CEP">
```

angular:

```
$scope.pegaCep = function () {
    var cep = $scope.endereco.cep;
    if(cep.length <= 8){
        return
    }else
    if(cep.length == 9){
        $http.get("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/pegaCep.php?cep="+$scope.endereco.cep).success(function (endereco){

            $scope.endereco = endereco;
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar melhor e sugerir onde aplicar a alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: Consegui fazer a validação, agora só preciso fazer com que a função dispare quando terminar de digitar os 9 digitos.

Comment: A função que vc diz é preencher os inputs com os dados do endereço?

Comment: Não, só o cep.
Depois que os 9 caracteres, do cep, forem preenchidos, dispara uma função que busca os outros dados do cep.
O que eu tenho hoje, é, ao sair do campo do cep, ele busca os dados, entendeu @durtto?

Comment: Se o CEP for errado, vc emite um aviso que está errado?

Comment: Não, isso eu não estou validando.

Comment: Consegui.
Coloquei a minha solução na descrição do post.

Comment: O ideal seria que você utilizasse uma *directive* de validação que iria receber como argumento um *callback* para ser chamado quando o campo estivesse válido.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer isso @Zignd?